# Change urls depending on landing page

Tags: php

I have two landing pages (homepage1 and homepage2).  If I land on homepage1, the logo link needs to change to homepage1 and keep it as I go to other pages. The same goes when I land on homepage2.  I tried -

```
if (strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 'homepage1.php') !== false) { 
    <a href='homepage1.php'><img src='logo.jpg'></a>
}

elseif (strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 'homepage2.php') !== false ) { 
    <a href='homepage2.php'><img src='logo.jpg'></a>
}
```

It works when I go to one page but anymore than one the url and logo are gone.  In other words, it doesn't hold on to the url.

I need it to hold on to the url based on what landing page I land on.  And it needs to hold on to the url, no matter how many pages I go to.

Is this possible?

Comment: You might want to look at setting a session variable.

Comment: Yes I agree but not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

As @DragonYen pointed out , you need to use session variable as it can be used to persist state information between page requests.

```
session_start();

$ref = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$page = explode("/", $ref); 

if($page[3] == "homepage1.php") { 
    $_SESSION['home'] = 1;
}

else if($page[3] == "homepage2.php")  {     
    $_SESSION['home'] = 2;
}
```

Now you can check for session variable home

```
 if ($_SESSION['home'] == 1) { 
    <a href='homepage1.php'><img src='logo.jpg'></a>
}

elseif ($_SESSION['home'] == 2) { 
    <a href='homepage2.php'><img src='logo.jpg'></a>
}
```

put this when you no longer need the session

```
unset($_SESSION['home'];
session_destroy();
```

Comment: I don't use sessions, but won't Brad need session_start(); someplace in there too?

Comment: I agree, but I was just trying to give him a hint, anyway fixed it , thanks

Comment: Thanks.  I'm getting this error -   Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at C:\wamp\www\animals\inc\header.php:31) in C:\wamp\www\animals\inc\header.php on line 31

Comment: DO NOT put any content before session_start() , put it at the very top of your file (yes even before html etc)

Comment: Ok I should of known that.... that removed the error but it's not displaying the logo with the url.

Comment: ok, so are you getting any error ? if not, is it not displaying the logo in only one page or in all the pages ?

Comment: No error.  The logo isn't displaying on all pages. If I add an else with <a href='homepage2.php'><img src='logo.jpg'></a> it works of course.  Just trying something to see what the issue is.

Comment: ok try removing the session_distroy() and code above it, i think the variable is getting deleted after navigation

Comment: Removed and same problem - No logo and url.

Comment: are you putting session_start in every page that you are trying to test ?

Comment: Yes.  I checked again and it's on all pages I'm testing.

Comment: I added an echo  <?php echo "hello"]; ?> where session_start();  is located for testing. I'm displaying the echo above all the code. Then I added below the if elsif statement <?php echo $_SESSION['home']; ?> but display's nothing.

Comment: so you are not seeing logo even in the home page ?

Comment: No not seeing it on any page.

Comment: One thing I noticed is the way you are comparing HTTP_REFERER see my updated answer

Comment: That displayed the logo but would only uses homepage2.  Back to your first code - This worked -  instead of !== false I tried == true and that worked.  The only issue now is when I use unset($_SESSION['home']);
session_destroy(); or one or the other homepage1 and homepage2 will not show the logo but the other pages show the logo plus and the correct url.  I have this code in the footer too.

Comment: try to remove this session destroy code block & see what happens